# How to convert hh:mm to mm:ss in Excel. iTunes copies mm:ss song length to hh:mm to Excel and I want to run an accumulative total. Thanks

Tags: excel, itunes

When I copy song times from iTunes 11.1.5 to Excel for Mac 2011 version 14.3.9 Excel reads the times as hh:mm instead of mm:ss.  How do I convert (transpose?) hh:mm to mm:ss in Excel?  I want to run a accumulative total for song time to fit my DJ volunteer time at dance club.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1** in **B1** enter:

```
=A1/60
```

and format **B1** as "mm:ss"